# Trouble with CSS rollover in Chrome - image disappears

Tags: css, google-chrome, rollover

Though in 1996 I had one of the top 5 Leonardo DiCaprio web-sites - I'm no programmer.  So I tried using 4ormat templates to make my life easier but they didn't have an option for image rollovers so I had to change the css and of course its causing problems for me.  It works fine in every browser - sometimes it even works fine in chrome!  But if you load it a bunch the first few images on the page will load and then disappear!  Its been great in every other browser!  What am I doing wrong??

http://sarahcrump.4ormat.com/retouching

the code looks like this:

```
    .rollover a{
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: transparent solid 0px;

    }    


    #erilynn a{
    height: 550px; 
    width: 393px; 
    background: url('http://4ormat-asset.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/1327226/0x550_1329240086.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    }
    #erilynn a:hover{
    background-position:  -393px;
    }
```

I know other people have run into this problem as well but have yet to discover a solution that works..  Anyone know whats up?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dev channel of Chrome, this seems to be a bug in Chrome (Webkit more specifically) than in your code.

You can check the bug report for Chrome at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111218

I have personally hit this problem few weeks ago in my code and sadly couldn't find a workaround.