# CSS Before & After Image Rollover

Tags: html, css

I posted a similar question a few days ago but i've narrowed down my problem and know exactly what I need now.

I've created a portfolio on 4ormat and need to insert a custom CSS code to have an rollover on each image so it shows the before/after.

This site shows exactly what I need - http://www.sarahcrump.com/retouching

I have that same theme and it's hosted on the same site.

The person who made that site actually posted on here a few years ago because of a rollover problem.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415517/trouble-with-css-rollover-in-chrome-image-disappears) was their post.

I tried just plugging that code into the custom CSS panel but didn't get any results.

I didn't think it would work because I figured I needed to put all the "before" images that appear when I hover somewhere.

I can provide any additional HTML/CSS code you need to show me where to plug in some things, just ask. Thanks everyone, really appreciate it.

Edit: Which of these codes would be best to post? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofi7k.png

Comment: provide code for what you have tried till now

Comment: After edit, still not code?  Just posting that you can give us code does not help.  It would make it far easier to fix if we could see it.

Comment: All I have tried is pasting the CSS code in this link I listed in the original post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415517/trouble-with-css-rollover-in-chrome-image-disappears

Comment: @SamDenton I'm sorry, I just didn't know what I needed to show. Which of these would be best to post? http://i.imgur.com/vjtvUxw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked over you question again, an I think that it would be easier in html, and just use this

```
<img id="test_button" src="test button.png" alt="Failed to load" onmouseover=" this.src='test button onhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='test button.png'"</img>
```

I think this is what you are looking for.  You can than use css to restyle how you wish.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great thanks for the response!! Do you mind looking at the imgur link and telling me what one of those sections I should post it in? I can copy over the code if you need it!

Comment: not really sure what you mean, I presume the gallery section.

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the gallery section - http://pastebin.com/fmsjwVUH

Think it's good in here?

Comment: I can't do anything with that, you have not actually said what you want!  just add my html where you want the image, changing the src for your own image and it should work fine.

Comment: Okay great i'll do that. Thank you for the help!